# SOLVED: Pretty print JSON using Golang templates

Tags: html, json, go, go-html-template

I am making a website using go templates. I need to print a variable containing JSON data to the screen. I'd like to pretty print it to the screen and haven't had any luck with that.

In flask I am able to do the following to accomplish this decently well:

```
{% autoescape false %} {{stringwithjsondata | safe | replace(",", "<br>")}} {% endautoescape %}
```

and was wondering if I could do something similar here.

I'm using the html/template package for the website.

EDIT: I over complicated this to eternity, I just used `<pre>` tags in the end with strings.replace to make it look good

Comment: You can do pretty much anything, just write a function to format it how you want. See https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs and https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#example_Template_func

Comment: You can use something like the sprig library: https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig